# Getting Text to appear at different times

Tags: beamer, equations

[image]

Is there a way to get the parts of this code to show up in this order:

1. The coefficients circled in blue.
2. The conditions circled in red.
3. The binomial coefficients circled in green.
4. The equations underneath circled in black.
5. The equations circled in purple.

This is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'cases*' environment
\newcommand\hstrut{\hphantom{{} + 1\binom{k}{2} {}}} % horizontal spacer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
a(n,3)=
\begin{cases*}
  1 \binom{k+2}{2} + 4 \binom{k+1}{2} + 1 \binom{k}{2} = 3k^2+3k+1 
    & if $n$ is $6k$  \\
  1 \binom{k+2}{2} + 5 \binom{k+1}{2} \hstrut = 3k^2+4k+1 
    & if $n$ is $6k+1$\\
  2 \binom{k+2}{2} + 4 \binom{k+1}{2} \hstrut = 3k^2+5k+2   
    & if $n$ is $6k+2$\\
  3 \binom{k+2}{2} + 3 \binom{k+1}{2} \hstrut = 3k^2+6k+3 
    & if $n$ is $6k+3$\\
  4 \binom{k+2}{2} + 2 \binom{k+1}{2} \hstrut = 3k^2+7k+4 
    & if $n$ is $6k+4$\\
  5 \binom{k+2}{2} + 1 \binom{k+1}{2} \hstrut = 3k^2+8k+5 
    & if $n$ is $6k+5$\\
\end{cases*} 
\]
\begin{align*}
&\textstyle 1 {{k+2}\choose{2}}  + 4 {{k+1}\choose{2}} + 1 {{k}\choose{2}} \\ 
\pause  &= 1((k+2)(k+1)) + 4((k+1)k) + 1(k(k-1)) \\ 
\pause  &= 2(3k^2+3k+1)
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using beamer `package`? What is your complete code, please?

Comment: I apologize, I've attached the code, and yes this is using the beamer package.

Comment: No, there was nothing wrong with the answer, the code worked, but after I asked the question I tried putting an extra $ around the binomial coefficient, and the code started working.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing your code with something that doesn't use a multitude of `$` symbols. The screenshot didn't have to be updated. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still true that one should not use `$$ ... $$` nor `\choose`. Also, `\pause` does not work in an `align` environment, but it does work in an `eqnarray` environment, which some users do not like. Anyway, neither of them is needed here. Other than that, you can uncover parts of equations with `\uncover`. Since there is a lot of repetition, one may create macros. As these are "junk macros", one may want to keep them local with `\begingroup...\endgroup`. Since we define them in frame, one can either make the frame `fragile` or use four (!) `#` fences.

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Uncovering an equation}
\begingroup
\newcommand\Coeff[1]{\uncover<2->{####1}}%
\newcommand\Binom[2]{\uncover<4->{\binom{####1}{####2}}}%
\newcommand\Sth[2]{\uncover<7->{=3k^2+####1k+####2}}%
\newcommand\If[1]{\uncover<3->{\text{ if $n$ is }####1}}%
\[
a(n,3)=%
\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}l@{}}
  \Coeff{1} \Binom{k+2}{2}  
  \Coeff{+4} \Binom{k+1}{2} \Coeff{+1} \Binom{k}{2} &\Sth{3}{1}\If{6k}\\
  \Coeff{1} \Binom{k+2}{2} \Coeff{+5} \Binom{k+1}{2}  &\Sth{4}{1}\If{6k+1}\\
  \Coeff{2} \Binom{k+2}{2} \Coeff{+4} \Binom{k+1}{2}  &\Sth{5}{2}\If{6k+2}\\
  \Coeff{3} \Binom{k+2}{2} \Coeff{+3} \Binom{k+1}{2}  &\Sth{6}{3}\If{6k+3}\\
  \Coeff{4} \Binom{k+2}{2} \Coeff{+2} \Binom{k+1}{2}  &\Sth{7}{4}\If{6k+4}\\
  \Coeff{5} \Binom{k+2}{2} \Coeff{+1} \Binom{k+1}{2}  &\Sth{8}{5}\If{6k+5}\\
\end{array} \right.
\]
\endgroup
\uncover<6->{\begin{multline*}
 1 \binom{k+2}{2}  + 4 \binom{k+1}{2} + 
1 \binom{k}{2}\\
\quad = 1((k+2)(k+1)) + 4((k+1)k) + 1(k(k-1)) \\ 
  = 2(3k^2+3k+1)
\end{multline*}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!